# FFMPEG convert RTSP to RTMP overlay pipeline

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming

I have ffmpeg command that I want to convert RTSP to RTMP broadcast.
Before the broadcast, I want to overlay the frame with an image.

So, here is my pipeline:

1. read stream from RTSP
2. overlay an image
3. broadcast RTMP (Youtube)

I tried some command, but I met the error message:

- Here is my command

The reason why I used anullsrc is because the RTMP server must input an audio stream, but my video stream has no audio

```
ffmpeg -i image.jpg -i <rtsp://server> -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]overlay"  -f lavfi -i anullsrc -rtsp_transport udp -t 12:00:00 -pix_fmt + -tune zerolatency -sstrict expreimental -f flv <rtmp:// server>
```

- Error Message

```
[rtsp @ 0000021890521700] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
The filters 'graph 0 input from stream 0:0' and 'Parsed_overlay_0' do not have a common format and automatic conversion is disabled.
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!
```

- all the message

```
Input #0, image2, from 'image.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1763 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 225x225 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn
Input #1, rtsp, from 'rtsp://~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~':
  Metadata:
    title           : RTMP Server 
    comment         : RTMP Server Session Description : standard
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.034000, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #1:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, 30 tbr, 90k tbn
Input #2, lavfi, from 'anullsrc':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 705 kb/s
  Stream #2:0: Audio: pcm_u8, 44100 Hz, stereo, u8, 705 kb/s
Codec AVOption tune (The metric that the encoder tunes for. Automatically chosen by the encoder by default) specified for output file #0 (rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (mjpeg) -> overlay:overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #1:0 (h264) -> overlay:main (graph 0)
  overlay (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (flv)
  Stream #2:0 -> #0:1 (pcm_u8 (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[rtsp @ 0000021890521700] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
The filters 'graph 0 input from stream 0:0' and 'Parsed_overlay_0' do not have a common format and automatic conversion is disabled.
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by myself.

Here is my command:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc  -rtsp_transport udp -i <rtsp:~> -i <image.jpg> -filter_complex "[1:v][2:v]overlay" -tune zerolatency -vcodec libx264 -t 12:00:00 -pix_fmt yuvj420p -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -sstrict expreimental -f flv <rtmp:~>
```

Thanks.